# Artisan serve all functions works perfectly, but when I run it on Xampp some functions doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys I'm having problem with my web app, I'm using the `php arstisan serve` command when I'm developing it on my PC, but when I run the web app on Xampp then connecting my phone to my I.P address so that I can use the web app there. The page loads and some of the forms submitted okay, but others are not when they are all working perfectly on my 127.0.0.1:8000(which is the development URL for laravel), by the way I'm using Vue axios post to all of my forms.

The error code is: 405 method not allowed.

> "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\Centralsocial\resources\views\User\feedbackpage.blade.php)"

I think the error is somewhere in this code:

```
<div id="app">
    <survey-component :user_id="<?php echo e(Auth::user()->id); ?>"></survey-component>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using api?

Comment: yes i am @Community

Comment: Is there definitely a logged in user? Also, a `405` error is a method not allowed which would mean that you're trying to access a route (url)  with the wrong HTTP verb (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`). Please can you add the code for your `survey-component` and your routes file?

Comment: @RossWilson yes but i just fixed it, i added a parameter of the user_id with after the axios post url.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is having this issue this is how i fixed it

*Vue Axios POST*

```
axios.post('/api/surveysubmit/' +this.user_id,{
q1: this.selected.q1,
q2: this.selected.q2,
```

I added the "+this.user_id" 
then in my Api

*API.PHP*

```
//  user submit survey
Route::post('surveysubmit/{user_id}', 'StudentController@surveysubmit');
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but hey it works on my end :)